# The homology of the dual of a (specific) chain complex

Tags: proof-verification, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I work over a field $k$. If $C$ is a chain complex, I will use the following convention for its dual:
$$(C^\vee)_n:=(C_{-n})^\vee.$$
In particular, the dual of a chain complex is again a chain complex. We also have the nice property that the natural pairing
$$C^\vee\otimes C\longrightarrow k$$
is a chain map (where $k$ is concentrated in degree $0$).

With this out of the way, here's the real question. Consider the chain complex
$$C:=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(k\,x_n\oplus k\,y_n)$$
with $|x_n|=0$, $|y_n|=1$, and differential $d(y_n):= x_n-x_{n-1}$. Its homology is
$$H(C) \cong k\,[x_0]\ ,$$
as all of the $x_n$ are closed and homologous, and none of them are exact (and the $y_n$ are not closed). The dual of $C$ is
$$C^\vee=\underbrace{\left(\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}k\,x_n^\vee\right)}_{\text{degree }0}\oplus\underbrace{\left(\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}k\,y_n^\vee\right)}_{\text{degree }-1}$$
with differential given by $d(x_n^\vee)=y_n^\vee-y_{n+1}^\vee$. All of the $y_n^\vee$ are closed, but they are also exact since
$$d\left(\sum_{k\ge n}x_n^\vee\right)=y_n^\vee.$$
From this, I would say that $H(C^\vee)=0$. However, by the usual $Ext$ stuff and since we are working over a field, we should have
$$H(C^\vee)\cong H(C)^\vee,$$
i.e. a $1$-dimensional vector space. What am I missing?

Comment: Just to understand the notation, $C_0 = \langle x_i : i\in \mathbb Z\rangle$, $C_1 = \langle y_i : i\in\mathbb Z\rangle$ and $C_1\to C_0$ is $dy_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$? Then $H_1(C)=0$ and $H_0(C)$ has dimension $1$ since all the $x_i$ are identified by $d$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You're right, thanks. Anyway, the point stands: what is the non-zero class in $H(C^\vee)$? It's probably something obvious that I'm stupidly missing...

Comment: The sum of all the duals of the $x_n$ is in the kernel of $d^0$, right? And it is the generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $V_0$ for the span of the $x_i$ and $V_1$ for the span of the $y_i$, and raise indices to dualize so you have
$$ 0 \longrightarrow V^0\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow V^1\longrightarrow 0$$

Then a functional $f \in V^0$ is in the kernel of $d$ if and only if we have $f(x_i) =  f(x_{i+1})$ for every $i$, or, what is the same, if and only if it is a scalar multiple of the functional $\theta = \sum \widehat x_i$, which is in the kernel of $d$, and is the generator of $H^0(C^\vee)$.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb now! Thanks!